# ASP.Net AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender not updating Textbox in code behind

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Have the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image ID="ibDateS" runat="server" ImageUrl="../SystemImages/calendar.gif" ToolTip="Click to show calendar" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" CssClass="showpointer" />                                                
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceStart" PopupButtonID="ibDateS" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtStart" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

It all works ok on the DOM and the textbox gets updated with the new date BUT when I try to get the value in code behind i.e. txtStart.Text it still has the original value set on Page_Load.

Have I missed something?

EDIT:
TextBox set originally in Page_Load (yes contained in if(!IsPostback)):

```
txtStart.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Get it later like so:

```
DateTime dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
```

Comment: how you try to get value..do you have any postback events

Comment: Where do you evaluate the text property in codebehind and where do you set it? I assume this is the standard problem: people forget to wrap their databinding part into a `if(!PostBack)` block.

Comment: show me your code plz.

Comment: Can you post Page_Load code.

Comment: See Edit above, no issue setting, no issue with the calendarextender changing the value in the textbox, just don't get the updated text value when clicking a button to save the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research apparently its an issue with setting the textbox to readonly or enabled="false" on the page.  Removing this and adding the following to page_load solved the problem:

```
txtStart.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't use [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property of page then plz use it and try to use you pageload code inside that. It seems that it may be the problem of `Page.IsPostBack`,Try for that

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
    // Your code for databind...
   }
}
```

Hope you understand and works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Enabled false preventing it to post the latest value.